# All the questions are explained "by their categories" or "according to their categories"

Tags: usage

Which of these sounds more natural in English.

- ***All the questions are explained "by their categories" or "according to their categories"***-
  Can I also express it in another way?

Comment: Sorry, this isn't clear. How is a question explained by its category? Please provide more context.

Comment: Let's say we have 10 questions. First two of them are from "vocabulary in context" category, next 2 of them are from "Rhetoric" category and so on. And I am trying to say that: "the first two questions are from "Vocab in context" category", the next two are from "Rhetoric". So, in this case am I explaining the questions by their categorires or according to their categories?

Comment: Don't talk about "explaining them by" anything. Talk about "explaining the questions" (whatever that means in your context -- we don't know), which you have grouped (or arranged) by category. Using _by_ of the _by category_ construction right after _explain_ gets confused with the  _explain by_ construction, when you're only asking about the topic order, not the method of explanation.